# Azure SQL read scale-out feature: Monitor queries on read-only replica

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are experiencing some performance issues when read-only replica is enabled on a premium tier in Azure SQL, which is very strange and unexplainable. I can find if a query is being executed on a read-only replica by using the following inbuilt function:

```sql
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability')
```

The above query returns `READ_ONLY` if run against the read-only replica. However, there is no way to **monitor read-only queries**.

As per [the following article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out), extended events and query store is not supported in the preview for read-only replica, whereas [the following article suggests that the read-scale-out feature is now generally available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/roadmap/azure-sql-database-announces-preview-of-read-scale-out-support-in-premium-service/). Still, I cannot monitor queries executed on read-only replica in the premium SQL database tier.

I can see a [user voice item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/34337935-monitor-queries-on-secondary-database-when-read-sc). Is there any other option to monitor read only workload?

Comment: Without the Query Store or Extended Events, I'd say currently, there isn't a way to get it done.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, you cannot use Query Store or Extended Events to monitor queries on read-only replicas but still can use [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) dynamic view, which can give you for example top queries by CPU consumption

```
SELECT TOP (25) MIN(query_stats.statement_text) AS [Statement Text],
SUM(query_stats.total_worker_time) / SUM(query_stats.execution_count) AS [Avg CPU Time],
query_stats.query_hash AS [Query Hash]
FROM (SELECT QS.*, SUBSTRING(ST.[text], (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.[text])
        ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END
            - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
     FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) AS ST) AS query_stats
GROUP BY query_stats.query_hash
ORDER BY [Avg CPU Time] DESC;
```

You can change the ORDER BY clause on below query to monitor other resources:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    (total_logical_reads/execution_count) AS avg_logical_reads,
    (total_logical_writes/execution_count) AS avg_logical_writes,
    (total_physical_reads/execution_count) AS avg_phys_reads,
    (total_worker_time/execution_count) AS avg_cpu_over_head,
total_logical_reads, total_logical_writes, total_physical_reads,
total_worker_time, execution_count, total_elapsed_time AS Duration,
plan_generation_num AS num_recompiles,
statement_start_offset AS stmt_start_offset,
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(text, statement_start_offset/2 + 1,
        (CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
            THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),text)) * 2
                ELSE statement_end_offset
            END - statement_start_offset)/2)
     FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) AS query_text,
      (SELECT query_plan FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)) AS query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
--JUST CHANGE THE ORDER BY TO GET THE OTHER RESOURCES
ORDER BY (total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes)/execution_count DESC
```

You may want to store the result of queries like the above for later analysis.

Comment: Shared queries will be executed on read/write database and will give stats of read/write database. Read-only replica databases are not exposed externally and cannot be connected from any client. Please correct me if i have misunderstood

Comment: @Rohit You just need to connect using ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in the connection string (or additional connection parameters in SSMS) to see the specifics of the read-only replica.